# The application has stpped unexpectedly

Tags: android, android-emulator

When I start the following app in Android emulator the app stops with the following error message : "The application Player (process kilbo.net) has stpped unexpectedly. Please try again."
There are no errors, warnings and I can't find anything in debugger related to the problem.
This is a common problem I have, not just with this app.

```
    package kilbo.net;

import java.io.IOException;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ProgressBar;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class Player extends Activity implements Runnable, OnClickListener{

   private TextView Status;
   private ProgressBar progressBar;
   private Button StartMedia;
   private Button Stop;
   private MediaPlayer mp;      

   @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

       Status = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Status);
        progressBar = (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progressBar);
        StartMedia = (Button) findViewById(R.id.StartMedia);
        Stop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.Stop);

//Removing this two lines "fixes" the problem. So the error is probably related to this
        StartMedia.setOnClickListener(this);
        Stop.setOnClickListener(this);                
    }        

   @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if(v.equals(StartMedia)){
            if(mp != null && mp.isPlaying()) return;
            MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
            try {
                mp.setDataSource("http://kilbo.net/musik/Norrskenet.mp3");
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            mp.start();               
            Status.setText("playingMedia");         
            progressBar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.VISIBLE);
            progressBar.setProgress(0);
            progressBar.setMax(mp.getDuration());
            new Thread(this).start();
        }

        if(v.equals(Stop) && mp!=null){
            mp.stop();
            mp = null;            
            Status.setText("Stop");
            progressBar.setVisibility(ProgressBar.GONE);
        }

   }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        int CurrentPosition= 0;
        int total = mp.getDuration();
        while(mp!=null && CurrentPosition<total){
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
                CurrentPosition= mp.getCurrentPosition();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                return;
            } catch (Exception e){
                return;
            }            
            progressBar.setProgress(CurrentPosition);
        }
    }


}


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    >
  <Button id="@+id/Stop"  
            android:layout_width="125px" android:layout_height="50px"
            android:background="#FF222222" android:text="Start" />
  <Button id="@+id/StartMedia"  
            android:layout_width="125px" android:layout_height="50px"
            android:background="#FF222222" android:text="Start" />
   <ProgressBar id="@+id/progressBar"  
            android:layout_width="125px" android:layout_height="50px"
            android:background="#FF222222" android:text="Start"
            style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal" />
  <TextView id="@+id/Status"  
            android:layout_width="125px" android:layout_height="50px"
            android:background="#FF222222" android:text="Start" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Find Logcat. Use it. Then fix the missing android:id attributes in layout/main.xml

Comment: Does StartMedia.setOnClickListener(this); need a separate id in main.xml, or should I add something to  <Button id="@+id/StartMedia"  
            android:layout_width="125px" android:layout_height="50px"
            android:background="#FF222222" android:text="Start" />? I have found the onClick attribute, but what am I supposed to put there? android:onClick="onClick"

Answer (score 0):

I think you get a NPE when de Debugger tries:
StartMedia.setOnClickListener(this);

You should try to find the Stacktrace.

Comment: A breakpoint here StartMedia.setOnClickListener(this); Tells me this: 02-24 12:06:17.818: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(369): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{kilbo.net/kilbo.net.Player}: java.lang.NullPointerException
But I cant figure out why.

Answer (score 0):

You say the error is

```
02-24 12:06:17.818: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(369): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{kilbo.net/kilbo.net.Player}: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Is your activity properly declared in your manifest?

Comment: I have more or less moved on since I asked the question. But if I'm not miss minded the problem was fixed by setting onClick in main.xml rather than in the java code.